# why is happening with my code at the moment to send cmdLineParser to main?

Tags: python

I would like to import my packages from other folders, but when I try to import my python files from other folders. it didn't work, how can I fix this??

```
/tool  
  /core    
    settings.py
   __init__.py
```

main

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import core.settings

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            settings.cmdLineParser()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "interrupted by user.."
        except:
            sys.exit()
```

settings.py

```
from optparse import OptionParser

def cmdLineParser(argv=None):
    a = 1 
    while True:
        print a
        a+=1
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is rarely an helpful description of your problem

Comment: my problem is I want to import my package from /core/settings.py to the main.py

Comment: what's the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

where is your main placed? what is the error exactly? try to explain your problem with more details.

Based on what I guess is your problem, to import function from another file use from foo import bar.

```
from tools.core import settings

#some code

settings.cmdLineParser()
```

or to import just a function

```
from tools.core.settings import cmdLineParser

#some code

cmdLineParser()
```

or you can use * to import all the functions in the file. but I guess it's not a good practice.

```
from tools.core.settings import *
```

or

```
import tools.core.settings

#some code

tools.core.settings.cmdLineParser()
```

But, after all it's all just a guess.